# Path "/modules/custom" is invalid while runing drupal generate:module

Tags: composer-php, drupal-8, drupal-console

I'm trying to install a Drupal's plugin while using drupal-console.
I run it in /var/www/drupalvm/drupal/web$

I checked my drupal.composer.json file and everything is correct i believe

```
"installer-paths": {
    "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
    "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
    "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
    "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
    "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
}
```

What i run:

```sh
drupal generate:module   --module="My checkout flow"
--machine-name="my_checkout_flow"
--module-path="/modules/custom"
--description="My checkout flow"
--core="8.x"
--package="LSB"
--composer
--dependencies="commerce:commerce_checkout"
```

Thank you

Comment: Please add the exact exception/error-message to the question.

Comment: Yikes sorry I didn't see I forgot to put it, here whats i get :

In Validator.php line 174:
                                                                        
  Path "/modules/custom" is invalid. You need to provide a valid path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're providing an absolute `--module-path` as `/modules/custom` which doesn't exist on your system.

You need to provide a relative path or existing absolute path instead.

The solution  is to either omit the leading `/` or use the absolute path:

```
--module-path='modules/custom'
# ... or ...
--module-path="$(realpath modules/custom)"
```